# python subprocess cannot read from stdout using popen in docker

Tags: python, bash, docker

I have a docker file that copies in a bash script and a python script from the host machine to /root in the docker's file system:

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y nc
COPY filter_text_telemetry.sh /root/
COPY read_data.py /root/
EXPOSE 8071
RUN cd /root
```

My python script is supposed to start the bash script as a subprocess and then gather data from it as follows:

```
p = Popen(["./filter_text_telemetry.sh"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.stdout.readline()
```

On my host machine, the python code works fine and is able to print out the data it gathers. In my docker container, it prints nothing and I'm not sure why. The docker container defaults to running everything as root. Could that be affecting the stdout pipe? If that is not it then what can I do to fix my issue?

Comment: The easy way to read this is that `filter_text_telemetry` is behaving differently; can you try to confirm that, or provide evidence to the contrary? (BTW, I note that you're copying it in with a `.sh` extension, but calling it without one).

Comment: The python script does have the `.sh` extension that was a typo on my part. As far as evidence goes if I run the script manually as `./filter_text_telemetry.sh` it works normally i.e. it prints the expected output. All the python script is doing is taking that output off of stdout and printing it out.

Comment: "Prints nothing" meaning you get an EOF and `p.stdout` returns, or "gets nothing" meaning the Python script hangs at that point?

Comment: BTW, one thing that can easily cause this is the shell script trying to write to stderr; since nothing in the Python is *reading* from stderr, that write will block. Not redirecting your stderr to a pipe unless you're going to arrange for something to reading that pipe would thus be eliminating a potential failure case.

Comment: `p.stdout` gets nothing. For example if I put it into a while loop that goes for 5 seconds, the python script will hang for 5 seconds and then return. I tried eliminating the `stderr` pipe but that didn't seem to help. The docker container defaults to run everything as root. Could this be a possible cause for my issue. I know that running things as root changes the environment. Could this fact affect how data gets written to stdout?

Comment: Not in and of itself. Could change things as a side effect of the contents of your script, but you haven't shown us the contents of your script, so there's nothing we can say about it. This question really calls for a [mcve] -- the shortest code someone else can run as-is to see the issue ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a key piece of information: what is the command you're giving to `docker run`?

That said, looking at your Dockerfile, you appear to misunderstand how the `RUN` instruction works and I suspect that is what's tripping you up.

As [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) says,

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

What this means is that any changes made to the filesystem by the command that is `RUN` will be preserved in the filesystem image that is being built. However, `cd` makes no changes at all to anything in the filesystem; it simply changes the current working directory (CWD) of the current process. Thus, while the process started by `RUN` will then have a different CWD, this is not saved and new processes (such as the process starting a new container made from that image) will start with the default CWD.

So here is most likely what's happening:

1. The image has `filter_text_telemetry.sh` and `read_data.py` in the `/root` directory.
2. You start your container from that image with something like `docker run MYIMAGE /usr/bin/python /root/read_data.py`.
3. The python interpreter is started with the default CWD of `/`, reads `/root/read_data.py` and starts executing that code.
4. The Python program attempts to run `./filter_text_telemetry.sh` which, because `.` (the CWD) is `/`, tries to find that file as `/filter_text_telemetry.sh`.
5. It's not there (because it's in `/root/filter_text_telemtry.sh`), and so the `Popen` fails.

There are various "proper" ways to fix this (such as having the Python program figure out what directory it lives in and look for `filter_text_telemetry.sh` in that directory, regardless of the CWD), but a common and easy solution is simply to put your scripts in `/` rather than `/root` so that the CWD when you start is the directory containing your scripts. (And remove that `RUN cd /root` instruction, since it's a no-op that can do nothing but mislead people.)